# Vb.net unable to cast COM object to Class type

Tags: vb.net, com

I have an issue on excel.ComAddin.Item("r12.abc").object which return an object, its of type Cognos.office.Connect, then call function on Connect class returns WrapperObject. I need to take the methods from Wrapperobject for further call.

```
Dim obj As Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn = _excel.COMAddIns.Item("r12.abc")


 If (obj.Connect) AndAlso obj.Object IsNot Nothing Then

 o = CType(obj.Object, Cognos.Office.BootStrap.Connect) --  Error says COM obj cant be convert to class but if i doesnt convert as class i cant read o.Wrapperobject()
 o.Wrapperobject()

 End If
```

Comment: It is a very common mishap.  Something very special needs to happen, the Office program is an out-of-process server.  So the "wrapper object" lives inside that other process as well, it needs to teleport from that process to your process.  Seems pretty easy to do for the Office objects but it is only because Microsoft did a lot of work to make that possible.  The author of that addin needs to provide a "proxy/stub", an extra library that knows how to serialize the object so it can be re-created in your process.  Few do.

Comment: Using the object late-bound is then the only correct way to do it, you have to keep it declared as Object.  A bit painful when IntelliSense can't help you, be sure you have a good manual.  Or by creating an add-in for the Office program yourself so your code runs inside the process as well.

Comment: [ask] Cognos.Office.BootStrap refers from one .dll file from IBM. In VBA I have a code "Application.COMAddIns("r12.abc").Object.Wrapperobject" its a excel plugin. I would like to call the Wrapperobject from vb.net. Because it a wrapper class which provides methods to use. Here I am checking COMADDIN in excel on r12.abc then call object, but COM cant be type casted. Kindly share some code snippet. Here author cant provide proxy/subs rite.. I am very new to this.